# Keras loss: 0.0000e+00 and accuracy stays constant

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have 101 folders from 0-100 containing synthetic training images.
This is my code:

```
dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
'Pictures/synthdataset5', labels='inferred', label_mode='int', class_names=None, color_mode='rgb', batch_size=32, image_size=(128,128), shuffle=True, seed=None, validation_split=None, subset=None,interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False,crop_to_aspect_ratio=False
)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', input_shape=(128,128,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(dataset,epochs=75)
```

And I always get the same result for every epoch:

```
Epoch 1/75
469/469 [==============================] - 632s 1s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - accuracy: 0.0098
```

What's wrong???

Comment: Hi @Charlie. How many labels you need to classify?

Comment: Hi @Charlie, can you describe your dataset a little bit? Like how many labels/classes are there, what do you  want to predict etc? At first glance it looks like you might have a either a wrong activation function and a wrong output number for th classes in your last layer, a worng loss function or your synthetic data could be not enough to learn from.

Comment: so i dont know the terminology between classes and labels, but basically im trying to guess the number of fruit in the image. there is 101 folders, with each picture in the folder having the number of fruit in the folder name. The folder names go from 0-100. there is 15000 pictures overall. Im sorry im quite new to this :)

Comment: @fabian it just doesnt seem like a coincidence that its always 0.0098 accuracy which would be expected from random guesses, or more likely picking the same number always. But I dont know how to change the last layer size because if i change it from one in model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')), it chucks an error, though i presume that it is the dimension size not the length

Comment: @adarshwase it says something like found 15000 images from 101 classes

Comment: @Charlie, it is not a coincident per se...your model isn't able to learn from the data as of right know which you can see because the loss is 0.

Comment: Can you also give us the output of: dataset.class_names

Comment: Ok, use this code in the last layer: `model.add(Dense(101, activation='softmax'))`. I think it will work fine now.

Comment: @adarshwase it says- valueerror:Shapes (None,1) and (None,101) are incompatible when i run the fit

Comment: @fabian it gives an array from 0 to 100 but in a weird order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out your loss might be the problem after all.
If you use SparseCategoricalCrossentropy  instead as loss it should work.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

After this you should adjust the last layer to:

```
model.add(Dense(101, activation='softmax'))
```

Also don't forget to import `import tensorflow as tf`
Let me know if this solves the issue.

Comment: It chucks an error that says from logits=true but the output argument was produced by softmax and thus doesn’t represent logits. It does train but would this affect the efficiency?

Comment: You should propabliy ditch the part with from_logits=true...  just replace it with tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy() because you don't have a logits tensor here :)